# How to remove Overfull \hbox (12.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11--11 []

Tags: line-breaking, warnings

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Keywords}[1]{\par\noindent
{\small{\em Keywords\/}: #1}}
\title{strong text}
\author{ \and
\centerline{Department of Computer Engineering,College of engineering,city}}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
```

Comment: Note that you can mark text as 'code' by using indenting each line by four spaces.  I tried to edit your code, but there are two problems that remain: (i) it is incomplete; (ii) `lines 11-11` are blank, so I'm not fully convinced this code is the code causing the problems (or I edited it wrongly).

Comment: Who taught you to use `\centerline` there? Please reprimand them.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for `\centerline` within the `\author` declaration, since the `\author` - set as part of `\maketitle` - is already centred. So, remove it (and the seemingly superfluous `\and`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\title{strong text}
\author{Department of Computer Engineering, College of Engineering, City}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Some abstract
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```